# How to detect "strikethrough" cells in an ODS spreadsheet file in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, spreadsheet, strikethrough, ods

I need to detect, within a given ODS spreadsheet file, cells that are crossed out ("strikethrough" format) with a Python script.

I found a solution (because it wasn't possible with "pandas" lib) to do so for Excel files with openpyxl, but that doesn't work with ODS files.

I loved to read the "font" attributes within the pandas lib (for ods and xlsx), but found nothing.
Than I found a working example to do it for .xlsx files, but not for .ods.

I tried without success ezodf- and pyexcel_ods-lib.

Optimal solution would be to iterate through all sheets/rows/columns with a possible function call "is_strikethrough()", a attribute "font.strike" or some means to read all (font-)attributes without the need to "deconstruct" the ODS internals.